# Procurar Elemento Pela <Value> Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Estou desenvolvendo uma automação e o site não me define algo padrão do elemento, e suas classe é usadas em outros elementos então gostaria de procurar ele por sua value. é possivel?

```
<span data-aura-rendered-by="83:6602;a" class="uiOutputText" data-aura-class="uiOutputText">RANCHO RIO CLARO BAR E RESTAURANTE LTDA</span>
```

Comment: Uma sugestão seria  buscar na estrutura html esse span, no caso existe o método document.querySelector() - isso satisfaz a sua necessidade? Ai poderia buscar o elemento pai primeiro e depois chegar no span

Comment: por value você quer dizer o texto entre as tags?

Comment: @LucasMiranda isso mesmo..

Comment: @Bart na vdd até os elemento pai não tem uma referencia padrão tbm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, você pode buscar o elemento usando como critério seu texto.

Utilize a linguagem XPATH para isso conforme o exemplo abaixo.

```cs
var span = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text()='RANCHO RIO CLARO BAR E RESTAURANTE LTDA']"));
```

Comment: Funcionou cara, estava me matando a alguns dias. Muito obrigado te amo<3